# How can i call attribute filters in magento catelog page

Tags: magento-1.9, filtered-nav

I am using magento 1.9.0.1, we are using a customized theme for my website. I need to call attribute filters to particular place in catalog page, So for this requirement I am using this code for displaying filters.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/layer_view')->setTemplate('catalog/layer/view.phtml')->toHtml()?>
```

Using this code I am able to display attributes and I am able to pass parameters also but products are not filtered can any one help me out from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to add the layered view using the layout XML's instead of injecting the block directly. Also, adding 2 or more of this block in one page might cause issues.

Make sure your category is an `anchor` category in the backend and via your templates `local.xml` (or `catalog.xml`) you can move around the block by adding it to the preferred parent

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Above would include it in the footer, now all you have to do is add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav');?>` to the `footer.phtml` and you're done!

Comment: By default theme and in my customized theme also the filters are working fine, but i need to place it in somewhere in my customized theme catalog page, there is the problem products are not filtered.

Comment: with above instructions you should be able to do so

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply now i got the cause. i need to get it in my list.phtml file.

Answer (score 1):

`$_item->getFilter()->getRequestVar()`

Comment: please do not just post code